# how to access pre-existing table from sqlite using python flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

i'm trying by using below code but gives error.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restless import APIManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///compData.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class getRecord(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['condition']

@app.route('/sample', methods=["GET"])
def home():
    b = getRecord.query.all()
    for usr in b:
        return usr.first_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

TraceBack :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "path\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "path/PycharmProjects/testGetConn/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    class conda(db.Model):
  File "path/PycharmProjects/testGetConn/test.py", line 18, in conda
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['condition']
KeyError: 'condition'
```

by using this [tutorial](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/05/building-restful-apis-with-flask-in-pycharm.html) i have created table using SQLAlchemy on that table above code working fine but when i'm trying to access from another DB it show error.

Comment: Do you change `__table__` parameter of your class when changing the db?

Comment: yes ,__table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['condition'] using this

Comment: can you give example it will more helpful started learning about flask today

Comment: please put the exact code which is throwing error in question

Comment: above code throwing error

Comment: Try to print `db.Model.metadata.tables` line before 
`__table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['condition']` and see if condition table exists in the output or not